# Why do I get a double console message for this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
var checkNameLenght = function(name,nameLenght,allowedLenght,defaultName) {

    var result;

    if(!(nameLenght <= allowedLenght) || !(/[^a-z]/i.test(name))) {
        result = name; 
    }
        else {
            if(opts.debug == true) {
                console.log(name+' is to long or contains special characters / numbers | Please choose a name shorter than '+allowedLenght+' characters or remove any character / number');
            }
            result = defaultName;
        }

    return result;

}
```

I use it to check the length of a string ( in my case the value of an input ) and if it contains any special characters or numbers.

I use it like so:

```
var input = 'Somevalue';

checkNameLenght(input ,input.length,16,'Username');
```

The only thing is that if the `input` string contains some of the above conditions than the console will output the message twice.

Why is that happening ?

Comment: When running the provided code manually in the JS Console I did not experience the double-printing error. Check everywhere that `checkNameLenght()` is being called to make sure it's not being called twice. Seeing a bit more code might be helpful.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I figured I'd be nitpicky and point out that you've spelled "length" as "lenght" through the entire function.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would suggest that this logs twice. Perhaps you're calling the `checknameLenght()` function more than once in the rest of the code?

Comment: The second code block is getting executed twice for some reason. Maybe it's in an external file, and you're importing that file twice?

Comment: @evilspoons I know, it doesn't cause any error for that matter, that are just some variables and I can name them as I wish. Also, I need it to be that way because of some other reasons. But I appreciate the fast noticing :)

Comment: Your console message seems incorrect - "too long or contains special characters" is the opposite of *not both*. I think you should use `&&` in the `if` clause instead of `||`. (And another spelling mistake but that doesn't matter in JavaScript :-) ).

Comment: I suppose I should just throw out a caution that I hope you don't also have something called "checkNameLeng*th*" in addition to Leng*ht* because a single typo could make your life very, very interesting in the future. Instead of using typos, a better practice would be to simply call it 'checkNameLengthNewTechnique()' or something until it's finished, assuming that is what you're doing.

Comment: For all of you, you were right, I had the function executed twice inside my code and that is why I had that message output twice in the console. Thank you for pointing me to that direction, I thought it was something else ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested it and it works just fine. Are you sure you are not calling the function twice?
And try to avoid whatever `opts.debug` does, just use plain old js with `if(console)`

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the function twice, I was looking for some other reasons, if I weren't asking here I would have give up on the function ... And opt.debug I use it if a user chooses to see the messages in the console or not, it's part of an jQuery plugin